# Southern hemisphere projections for Landsat upsets GRASS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis, grass-gis, landsat

Does anyone have the last word on why Landsat scenes don't project in the southern hemisphere. This causes no end of trouble in GRASS, less so in QGIS.

What I mean is, take an original scene from USGS, open it in Erdas Viewfinder, go to ImageInfo|Projection and it reports;

```
Spheroid Name; WGS 84  
Datum Name:    WGS 84  
UTM Zone;      55  
North or South; North
```

For that scene I can see countryside which I am pretty sure is in the southern hemisphere, that is if I am as well (I am....I think...this is driving me crazy...)

In QGIS if I open a new project and set the CRS to UTM55S EPSG 32755 and then open the Landsat scene, it opens the layer and displays it with sensible (i.e. positive) coordinates, but in the Layer Properties it reports the Layer Spatial Reference System as

`+proj=utm +zone=55 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

and in the General tab the Coordinate Reference System as

`EPSG:32655 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 55N`

If I then set the layer CRS to the south, the map jumps out of view, I 'Zoom to extents' and the map displays but with a negative coord.

And then generally all sorts of trouble in GRASS. I am using GRASS.7.svn so perhaps not relevant to report that here. But typically will not display maps unless they are reprojected to the south before importing to GRASS.

I am working around this, but I want to know if it something that is going to 'break' with improvements to GRASS and QGIS, or is it an embedded problem in Landsat and likely that QGIS is mature enough now that this will always be the case.

Further detail comes from the _mtl.txt metadata file which comes with the bands, all of that is reproduced below.

`GROUP = L1_METADATA_FILE
  GROUP = METADATA_FILE_INFO
    ORIGIN = "Image courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey"
    REQUEST_ID = "0101103234777_00001"
    PRODUCT_CREATION_TIME = 2011-03-23T20:42:47Z
    STATION_ID = "EDC"
    LANDSAT5_XBAND = "1"
    GROUND_STATION = "ASA"
    LPS_PROCESSOR_NUMBER = 0
    DATEHOUR_CONTACT_PERIOD = "1002523"
    SUBINTERVAL_NUMBER = "01"
  END_GROUP = METADATA_FILE_INFO
  GROUP = PRODUCT_METADATA
    PRODUCT_TYPE = "L1T"
    ELEVATION_SOURCE = "GLS2000"
    PROCESSING_SOFTWARE = "LPGS_11.3.0"
    EPHEMERIS_TYPE = "DEFINITIVE"
    SPACECRAFT_ID = "Landsat5"
    SENSOR_ID = "TM"
    SENSOR_MODE = "BUMPER"
    ACQUISITION_DATE = 2010-01-25
    SCENE_CENTER_SCAN_TIME = 23:59:40.5160690Z
    WRS_PATH = 93
    STARTING_ROW = 84
    ENDING_ROW = 84
    BAND_COMBINATION = "1234567"
    PRODUCT_UL_CORNER_LAT = -33.6323837
    PRODUCT_UL_CORNER_LON = 143.9028043
    PRODUCT_UR_CORNER_LAT = -33.6701041
    PRODUCT_UR_CORNER_LON = 146.4800644
    PRODUCT_LL_CORNER_LAT = -35.5314421
    PRODUCT_LL_CORNER_LON = 143.8314666
    PRODUCT_LR_CORNER_LAT = -35.5719202
    PRODUCT_LR_CORNER_LON = 146.4680652
    PRODUCT_UL_CORNER_MAPX = 212700.000
    PRODUCT_UL_CORNER_MAPY = -3725700.000
    PRODUCT_UR_CORNER_MAPX = 451800.000
    PRODUCT_UR_CORNER_MAPY = -3725700.000
    PRODUCT_LL_CORNER_MAPX = 212700.000
    PRODUCT_LL_CORNER_MAPY = -3936600.000
    PRODUCT_LR_CORNER_MAPX = 451800.000
    PRODUCT_LR_CORNER_MAPY = -3936600.000
    PRODUCT_SAMPLES_REF = 7971
    PRODUCT_LINES_REF = 7031
    PRODUCT_SAMPLES_THM = 7971
    PRODUCT_LINES_THM = 7031
    BAND1_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_B10.TIF"
    BAND2_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_B20.TIF"
    BAND3_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_B30.TIF"
    BAND4_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_B40.TIF"
    BAND5_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_B50.TIF"
    BAND6_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_B60.TIF"
    BAND7_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_B70.TIF"
    GCP_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_GCP.txt"
    METADATA_L1_FILE_NAME = "L5093084_08420100125_MTL.txt"
    CPF_FILE_NAME = "L5CPF20100101_20100331_09"
  END_GROUP = PRODUCT_METADATA
  GROUP = MIN_MAX_RADIANCE
    LMAX_BAND1 = 193.000
    LMIN_BAND1 = -1.520
    LMAX_BAND2 = 365.000
    LMIN_BAND2 = -2.840
    LMAX_BAND3 = 264.000
    LMIN_BAND3 = -1.170
    LMAX_BAND4 = 221.000
    LMIN_BAND4 = -1.510
    LMAX_BAND5 = 30.200
    LMIN_BAND5 = -0.370
    LMAX_BAND6 = 15.303
    LMIN_BAND6 = 1.238
    LMAX_BAND7 = 16.500
    LMIN_BAND7 = -0.150
  END_GROUP = MIN_MAX_RADIANCE
  GROUP = MIN_MAX_PIXEL_VALUE
    QCALMAX_BAND1 = 255.0
    QCALMIN_BAND1 = 1.0
    QCALMAX_BAND2 = 255.0
    QCALMIN_BAND2 = 1.0
    QCALMAX_BAND3 = 255.0
    QCALMIN_BAND3 = 1.0
    QCALMAX_BAND4 = 255.0
    QCALMIN_BAND4 = 1.0
    QCALMAX_BAND5 = 255.0
    QCALMIN_BAND5 = 1.0
    QCALMAX_BAND6 = 255.0
    QCALMIN_BAND6 = 1.0
    QCALMAX_BAND7 = 255.0
    QCALMIN_BAND7 = 1.0
  END_GROUP = MIN_MAX_PIXEL_VALUE
  GROUP = PRODUCT_PARAMETERS
    CORRECTION_METHOD_GAIN_BAND1 = "CPF"
    CORRECTION_METHOD_GAIN_BAND2 = "CPF"
    CORRECTION_METHOD_GAIN_BAND3 = "CPF"
    CORRECTION_METHOD_GAIN_BAND4 = "CPF"
    CORRECTION_METHOD_GAIN_BAND5 = "CPF"
    CORRECTION_METHOD_GAIN_BAND6 = "IC"
    CORRECTION_METHOD_GAIN_BAND7 = "CPF"
    CORRECTION_METHOD_BIAS = "IC"
    SUN_AZIMUTH = 74.7905248
    SUN_ELEVATION = 52.8328918
    OUTPUT_FORMAT = "GEOTIFF"
  END_GROUP = PRODUCT_PARAMETERS
  GROUP = CORRECTIONS_APPLIED
    STRIPING_BAND1 = "NONE"
    STRIPING_BAND2 = "NONE"
    STRIPING_BAND3 = "NONE"
    STRIPING_BAND4 = "NONE"
    STRIPING_BAND5 = "NONE"
    STRIPING_BAND6 = "NONE"
    STRIPING_BAND7 = "NONE"
    BANDING = "N"
    COHERENT_NOISE = "N"
    MEMORY_EFFECT = "Y"
    SCAN_CORRELATED_SHIFT = "Y"
    INOPERABLE_DETECTORS = "N"
    DROPPED_LINES = "N"
  END_GROUP = CORRECTIONS_APPLIED
  GROUP = PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
    REFERENCE_DATUM = "WGS84"
    REFERENCE_ELLIPSOID = "WGS84"
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_THM = 30.000
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_REF = 30.000
    ORIENTATION = "NUP"
    RESAMPLING_OPTION = "CC"
    MAP_PROJECTION = "UTM"
  END_GROUP = PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
  GROUP = UTM_PARAMETERS
    ZONE_NUMBER = 55
  END_GROUP = UTM_PARAMETERS
END_GROUP = L1_METADATA_FILE
END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if this 2nd answer is a faux-pas and I should've edited my previous answer but BWill has asked a different question in his answer.

I have just tested some USGS landsat imagery (as downloaded) in ArcGIS, ENVI, QGIS and GDAL. ArcGIS and ENVI correctly identify the projection and place it correctly in the southern hemisphere.  GDAL correctly identifies the projection. However, I suspect there is a bug/feature in QGIS as it is NOT recognising the projection correctly. For the couple of southern hemisphere scenes I just tried - QGIS shows "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs" which is incorrect (and not what is reported by GDAL). Which is strange, as I'm under the impression that QGIS uses GDAL as its data provider.

Comment: both ultimately use PROJ.4 to handle projection issues, though they may be linked against different versions or there may be some QGIS specific issue which was introduced.

Answer (score 5):

The Landsat GeoCover data use a non standard UTM projection for the Southern hemisphere.

All you need to do is assign the Northern projection to the Southern images and it will be in the correct location and you will be able to reproject the images on the fly.

Comment: In GRASS?  And why would USGS be doing "non standard"?

Comment: Why are they using non-standard...no idea, sometimes people do strange things :)

Comment: ujjwalesri appears to be right. You should be able to use gdal_warp -s_srs EPSG:32655 -t_srs EPSG:32755 to "fix" it. I guess the main reason there are two hemispheres for each UTM zone is to avoid negative values which isn't a problem if all your data uses the same projection, which presumably is what USGS does. Although it wouldn't surprise me if this was an oversight in the early days of LANDSAT that then had to stay.

Answer (score 3):

Problems with southern hemisphere projections for LANDSAT data in GRASS/GDAL seems to exist since long. Here are some discussions in this regard:

1. [[GRASS5] Problems with UTM/southern hemisphere](http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2004-October/015720.html)
2. [r.in.gdal unclean import of southern UTM zone](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/773)
3. [Win7 GRASS 7 & i.landsat.toar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/win7-grass-7-i-landsat-toar), here there's a mention as follows in question

> I have taken care to reproject the
>   images properly since there is
>   incorrect metadata for Landsat in the
>   southern hemisphere.

You could also try contacting USGS directly for information via this [web form](http://landsat.usgs.gov/contactus.php).

Comment: No 3. would be me starting to tug at my hair a little. Most of it is gone nowadays or at least grey....

Answer (score 3):

USGS Landsat imagery is supplied with a Northern Hemisphere UTM projection.  Scenes that are in the Southern Hemisphere have negative Y coordinates, this means they will display in the correct location south of the equator.  Basically, don't worry about it. If it bothers you, reproject your data.

Comment: HI lpinner, is the use of negative Y coords consistent with the EPSG standard?

Comment: EPSG isn't a 'standard' just a database of well known coordinate reference system definitions. I see no problem with negative coordinates, though it is convention to avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

The correct definition of 55S is:

```
# WGS 84 / UTM zone 55S
<32755> +proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs  <>
```

but you have omitted +south above. Hence it fails.

I have been using UTM on southern hemisphere in GRASS without problems.

Comment: Hi Markus, the text in my post is reproduced from USGS. I haven't omitted anything....       Why would USGS have gone for non-standard metadata?     They must have had the expectation that some systems could read the output correctly. Are GRASS and GDAL different to the standard which USGS were working to at the time?

Comment: I don't know about USGS but GDAL and GRASS follow the EPSG standard for many years.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted USGS;

`Hi USGS   when I use Landsat imagery in GDAL GIS (GRASS and QGIS) I have trouble with scenes which should be projected into the southern hemisphere. What protocol is USGS working to? Is it consistent with EPSG?     thanks.`

Their reply;

`Thank you for contacting the USGS Earth Resources Observation and Science (EROS) Center.
The southern UTM Zone projection has been removed to avoid complications with some cartographic products.  Although southern hemisphere scenes will incorrectly be tagged as northern hemisphere scenes, the data and coordinates will be accurate and displayed correctly.
Best regards, 
Customer Services
Technical Services Support Contract to the
USGS Earth Resources Observation and Science Center
47914 - 252nd Street
Sioux Falls, SD 57198`

So who is right? They did not discuss EPSG and GDAL. Whilst I accept that these are GIS standards and not image processing protocols, what cartographic products do project Landsat correctly in the southern hemisphere?

Even though this is an answer from me the originator, as far as I know with GIS.Stackexchange the bounty still stands!